# How to stream Mac desktop to Windows Laptop

Tags: mac, mac-mini

My plan is to use stationary Mac Mini through remote control from on my Laptop.
How do I do that?

My goal is to have supersmooth experience just like I would be using Mac normal way.

To people that may consider this is offtopic and "supersmooth" is subjective, I'll say that I am aiming for <50ms at 1080p while using host in range of, let's say 300km (in Europe).

For connection, I'll be using wi-fi 50mbits asymmetric 1/8 for my Mac and typical Cafe wifi (at my current place about 8mbits asymmetric 1/10) to connect my Laptop.

Supersmooth may be called 60 fps-like (although 30 should be enough for office stuff).

I am planning to code remotely on mac from laptop. So basically using IDE, few pdfs, email and web browser with multiple tabs.

Recently, I have found software called AnyDesk, which claims it has all I need, except Mac support, so for now (and maybe later, since AnyDesk is quite expensive) I have to find something else.

Comment: I very often need to access my machine in the UK from a small island in the middle of the Atlantic. Forget "smooth", let alone "super". Accept 1 fps, at best.

Comment: Your situation is not (or rather may not be) applicable to me. Please take a look into specifics that I provided.

Comment: You could test it for the price of a cup of coffee at your local Starbucks.In fact, I'd highly recommend doing that for whatever solution you go for. Use TeamViewer as a basic 'test it for free' without having to configure your firewall/port forwarding, though long-term you'd have to buy it [not cheap] or it keeps disconnecting after a short time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want screen sharing / remote desktop software? VNC Viewer for PC looks like it would be your friend in this case.

Here is an article that should help you.

http://www.howtogeek.com/214220/how-to-access-your-macs-screen-from-windows-and-vice-versa/

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for. Do you happen to know (considering connection is flawless) is it really smooth to use? I plan to work like that when I am traveling.

Comment: The 'smooth' experience is at the mercy of the speed of the internet connection between the Windows machine and the Mini. Even though you may consider the connection 'flawless', and it may be that way most of the time, be prepared for a less than smooth experience..

Comment: I've added more info in topic, please take a look :)